# UI alignment problems with Xcode9 which is working good with xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, xcode-storyboard, autoresize

I have iOS project code which is developed by using `XCode 6.2` and iOS8 SDK in **Objective-C**.

Now I have compiled the same source code using XCode 9 and iOS SDK11.

But all my UI alignments got changed once I start rotating the device.

The code has implemented using below UI elements

- Xib
- Storyboard
- Programmed UI

So now, I am trying to figure out what is the problem with the source code which misbehaves with `XCode 9` and working fine with `XCode 6` in orientations of the device portrait and landscape.

Some light on this problem will be helpful to figure what actually went wrong with the code. (Auto resize / Auto layout / size classes / programmatically UI alignments).

Comment: Using the Debug View Hierarchy can go a long way to helping you figure out what's going on with your layout. To get any help here, you need to provide much more detail about what you're doing, and what's going wrong. See: [ask]

Comment: there are a-lot of changes in Auto-layout and size class. Share more info to understand your problem.

Comment: I would suggest attaching some code snippets and screenshots if you can.